# stacking of thumbnails in view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am fairly new to android and I was able to get answers to my queries through browsing the SO archive.

1. My application is related to rendering all the image thumbnails having longitude & latitude  on to the mapview in stacked manner.
2. I figured out, overlay item/overlay may not be good choice as the API's provide access only to drawable objects. Creating a drawable object from the bitmap is not recommended. Mostly the scope is related to drawable resources like markers.

How should I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should look at fedorvlasov's lazyAdapter, it has a very good implementation of using a separate thread for loading images:

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

if you're trying to load them from images you already have it can work too, just requires some modifing...